# Can't load images from public folder, built with webpack

Tags: angularjs, svg, webpack

I recentley migrated from grunt and have som trouble with getting webpack to work. All the images are processed and added in the public folder, created when the application is built . Here is the public folder after it has been built :

[image: app structure]

In the index.html file I am referencing the path to the `ts-logo.svg` like this: `src="content/images/ts-logo.svg"`

I know the image is there because i can see it the sorces window in devtools as well:

[image: image source]

Why there is only one images within the folder, I have no clue. When i open the svg file in devtools the file is empty, running `wget` from the terminal says otherwise:

```
wget http://localhost:1384/content/images/ts-logo.svg
--2017-11-01 15:17:29--  http://localhost:1384/content/images/ts-logo.svg
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:1384... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 65 [image/svg+xml]
Saving to: ‘ts-logo.svg.1’

ts-logo.svg.1       100%[===================>]      65  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-11-01 15:17:29 (12,9 MB/s) - ‘ts-logo.svg.1’ saved [65/65]
```

Answer (score 0):

The public folder was always empty beacuse I was running `webpack-dev-server` in my `package.json` script. Running `webpack`, built the public folder as I wanted it.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue! at my end while manually configuring webpack in angular 1.x project

Tried following configuration for loading of images in webpack, now some files are loaded at public path:

`{
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=./assets/images/[name].[ext]&publicPath=./'
        }`

as:
[screenshot of browser after image load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTvsD.png)

Comment: how did you end up solving it?